# как связать html и php-файлы?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Добрый день. Недавно начал изучать html и php, и столкнулся с проблемой, которую никак не могу решить. Есть простейшая html-форма для введения значений 5 полей, и php-файл, который должен записывать введенные данные в БД. К php прикреплен файл, содержащий данные для входа (связка с ним работает и данные не из формы, а вбитые как значения переменных,отправляет нормально). Однако, при попытке ввести данные в форму страница просто обновляется.Соответственно, ничего не выводится и не записывается в БД. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка? (у меня есть смутное чувство, что для этого нужно прописать что-то в php, связанное со ссылками,но вот что?)

Upd0: добавил в  index.html кнопку с submitom и переправил названия полей (спасибо  за подсказку ArchDemon'у и прошу прощения - делал все это в жестком цейтноте). На всякий случай убрал экранирование символов. Увы, это ничего не дало. Может, я ставлю неправильное условие или что-то такое?
P.S. Насколько моих обрывочных знаний хватает, я припоминаю, что php работает раньше html. Правда ли это и не в этом ли заключается проблема?

UPD1: Решил упростить файлы настолько, насколько это возможно. Заодно проверил через GET - так результат просто записывается в адресную строку. Через POST опять же, обновление и никаких результатов.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>HTML-форма добавления новых данных</title>
</head>

<body>
<form  aсtion="test.php" method="post"> 
<br><br> № контракта <input name="numer_contracta"  maxlength=23 size=23>     
 <button type="submit" >Отправить на сервер</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```html
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["numer_contracta"])) {
require_once 'connection.php'; // подключаем скрипт
  // подключаемся к серверу
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
        or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));    
    // создание строки запроса
     $query ="INSERT INTO contracts (nomer_contracta) VALUES('$_POST["$numer_contracta"]')";
 }   
  // выполняем запрос
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка!" . mysqli_error($link));  
    if($result)
    {
        echo " Данные добавлены";
    // закрываем подключение
    mysqli_close($link); 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Неужели реально необходимо использовать символ `№` в названиях переменных и именах столбцов таблицы? Что выводится на экран. Если ничего не выводится, смотрите лог ошибок

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Отправить" />` в самом конце формы, можете бить по лицу тех, кто говорит, что на смену сабмиту пришел обычный `button`

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае у Вас нет действия для отправки html формы (т.е кнопки submit), по нажатию на которою содержимое формы уйдет на сервер.

Чтобы понять что такое отправка данных формы на сервер и как это работает почитайте [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/otpravka-dannykh-formy)

про кнопку submit и для чего она предназначена в форме [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/knopki)

Comment: Поставил, упростил до минимума, изменил названия на более удобочитаемые и поменял условие - но результат тот же, увы. С чем это может быть связано теперь?

Comment: if (!=empty($_POST["numer_contracta])) 1. зачем знак =   ? 2. где закрывающие скобки?

Comment: 1.= - действительно мой косяк,однако результат не изменился. 2. Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: после numer_contracta  нет скобки

Comment: Скобки? Я заметил,что не хватает кавычек (исправил,результат тот же), но.. Одна круглая скобка для if'а, вторая для empty, квадратная для POST'a. Что-то еще должно быть, а я пропустил? (прошу прощения, если что - спал очень мало)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (isset($_POST['numer_contracta']) && !empty($_POST['numer_contracta'])) {
            require_once 'connection.php'; // подключаем скрипт
            $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
            $query ="INSERT INTO contracts (nomer_contracta) VALUES('".$_POST["numer_contracta"]."')";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка!" . mysqli_error($link));

            header('location: test.php?status=' . ($result ? 'success' : 'fail'));
            die();
        } else {
            die('Empty data');
        }
    }

    $status = isset($_GET['status']) && in_array($_GET['status'], ['success', 'fail']) ? $_GET['status'] : '';

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <title>HTML-форма добавления новых данных</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?if (!empty($status)) {
            echo ($status == 'success' ? 'данные добавлены' : 'данные не были добавлены');
        }?>

        <form  method="post"> 
        <br><br> № контракта <input name="numer_contracta">     
         <button type="submit" >Отправить на сервер</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Объединил test.php и index.html.
Как это работает. 
Заполняешь форму -> submit -> браузер обращается к test.php методом POST -> обработка данных из POST в test.php и запись в базу -> редирект на test.php методом GET с параметром.
Проверял без базы.

Comment: Благодарю,но и эта версия не работает. Уже грешу на хостинг. Как только проверю на локальном сервере, отпишу о результатах.

Comment: Проверил на localhost с базой, все работает. Файл test.php лежит в корне, также у меня включены short_open_tag. В случае ошибок в любом случае должен быть вывод на экран.

Comment: Прошу прощения за столь долгое отсутствие. Запускаю на localhost с базой - тот же результат.  short_open_tag = On. Базовый OpenServer,  Apache-Php-7, PHP-7.1,MySQL 5.7.
Честно говоря, уже опускаются руки. Я не знаю, может, я что-то ну очень очевидное упускаю?